# Is the power function strictly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $p\in(1,+\infty)$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \phi_p:  \ & \mathbb{K} \longrightarrow [0,+\infty)\\
    & s \ \longmapsto \ 
    \phi_p(s):=|s|^p,
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$(\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ o $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C})$.
For all $u, v\in[0,+\infty)$, $u\neq v$, and $\lambda\in(0,1)$,
\begin{equation*}
    |\lambda u+(1-\lambda)v|^p<\lambda |u|^p+(1-\lambda)|v|^p. 
\end{equation*}
I have proved for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ using Hölder's inequality but I cannot prove for
$\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: assume wlog $u \ne 0$, let $w=v/u$ and note that for $|w|$ of fixed modulus, $ |\lambda +(1-\lambda)w|$ is maximal when $w \ge 0$ so one reverts to the real positive case as RHS depends only on $|w|$

Comment: I changed the title. "Modulo" usually means an entirely different thing, of arithmetic nature. Using that word in the title was misleading, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Hölder's inequality also holds for complex numbers so your proof probably works for that case as well.

There's also a simple reduction from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as follows.

Suppose that $u = a+ib$ and $v = c+id$. The inequality becomes
\begin{equation}
\left|\lambda a + (1-\lambda)c + i[\lambda b + (1-\lambda)d]\right|^p \le \lambda\left|a + ib\right|^p + (1-\lambda)\left|c + id\right|^p,
\end{equation}
or equivalently
\begin{equation}
\left((\lambda a + (1-\lambda)c)^2 + (\lambda b + (1-\lambda)d)^2\right)^{p/2} \le \lambda\left(a^2 + b^2\right)^{p/2} + (1-\lambda)\left(c^2 + d^2\right)^{p/2}.
\end{equation}
Notice that $(\lambda a + (1-\lambda)c)^2 \le \lambda a^2 + (1-\lambda)c^2$ and $(\lambda b + (1-\lambda)d)^2 \le \lambda b^2 + (1-\lambda)d^2$, it suffices to prove that
\begin{equation}
(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^{q} \le \lambda x^q + (1-\lambda)y^q,
\end{equation}
where $x=a^2 + b^2, y=c^2+d^2$ and $q=p/2$.